# how to select values from tensor contained in np.array

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have this huge tensor from which I just want to keep selected tensors.

Background - first contains coordinates of quadrilaterals being predicted.

```
np.shape(coords_detached) =  (15969, 8)
coords.shape() =   torch.Size([15969, 8])
```

The second, contains same coordinates but filtered after selection using NMS, for this discussion just say I select 9 rows from above tensor. 8 coordinates + 1 confidence score 
But NMS is being done in numpy so I detach the tensors.

```
coords_nms = torch.tensor(nms_coords_, dtype=torch.float32)

coords_nms.shape() =  torch.Size([9, 9])
```

So now I want to select just these 9 rows from the original tensor, coz it had the gradient information that gets lost during detach() and numpy nms.

I tried this :

```
s = torch.ones_like(nms_coords_)
s *=-1

nms_coords = torch.where(coords == coords_nms[:,:-1], coords, s)
nms_coords = nms_coords[nms_coords>=0]
nms_coords.reshape(-1, 8)
```

to iterate through `coords` and match value `coords_nms` and just store those. but it needs same dimension at `axis=0`

The iterative loop would be the following but how to do it using tensor notation :

```
poo = []
for x in coords:
    for z in nms_coords_:
       if sum(x[:] == z[:-1]) == 8 :
            poo.append(z[:-1])
```

Comment: can your nms algorithm returns the indices of the selected corrdinates?

Comment: That's an idea I have been toying with, but how to keep index to bbox mapping ?